# BlackBerry 9700 can not display the links correctly

Tags: html, blackberry

I have a page that look like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white" text="black">
<a href="first.asp">First</a><br><br>
<a href="databaseConnectionTest.aspx">Database Connection Test</a>
</body>
```

It should display two links, where if I put the cursor on, the cursor will become a finger shape and allow me to click.

However, I tried many times but the blackberry browser is not allowing me to click on the links.

Can anyone tell what is going on? And how to get it to work?

Edited according to the comments. Still have the same problem.

Comment: Your links should  be inside the `<body>`, not in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that all links in the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/html40.txt) are of the form:

```
<a href="URI">text</a>
```

Pay special attention to the quotes.

Furthermore, as @Joachim Sauer points out, your links should be in the `<body>`, not in the `<head>`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have made the change, and it still does not let me click the link, most of the time.

Comment: @Johnyy, now I'm surprised. I cut and pasted your HTML file into my local webserver and accessed the file on my BlackBerry 9700. I was able to click both links just fine. Works for me...